# Not able implement authentication - CakePHP

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I am trying to implement authentication following the steps in the cookbook however see that the Auth->identify() function is still returning nothing to the $user variable, like credentials are not found.
I have a table name called **Usuarios** and I want to user the fields **email** and **contrasena** (password) to authenticate.

Here's what I did:

**AppController.php**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => ['finder' => 'auth',
                    'userModel' => 'Usuarios']
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Usuarios',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer() 

]);
$this->Auth->allow(['display']);
```

**UsuariosController.php**

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Tu usuario o contraseña es incorrecta.');
    }
}
```

**login.ctp**

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**UsuariosTable.php**

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'email', 'contrasena'])
        ->where(['Usuarios.estado' => 1]);

    return $query;
}
```

Your help is really appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make some changes according to **email** and **username** :

```
  public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/eom/rLo49

Comment: @AndrésBadilla if this answer really help you mark as a right so might be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

A silly guess

in your `login.ctp`

```
<?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
```

Should be

```
<?= $this->Form->control('contrasena') ?>
```

Comment: Yes it was like this but the comment from Ahmed was correct and the link was very accurate as i needed some changes to adapt to Spanish correctly.